# Laplacian in polar coordinates (idea)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

As we know using chain rule, we can compute the Laplacian in polar coordinates: for $u=u(r,\theta)$ it holds
$$\Delta u=u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta}$$
There is something behind this formula that I don't get. If we forget about Cartesian coordinate system and transformation formulas, considering $u=u(r,\theta)$ "independently" then why shouldn't we have $\Delta u=u_{rr}+u_{\theta \theta}$. Isn't this how the Laplacian is defined? What fails here? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The Laplacian is initially defined in Cartesian coordinates. If you switch to polar coordinates, then you are still dealing with the *same operator*, so you need to use the chain rule to get a form which only involves derivatives with respect to $r$ and $\theta$. In other words, $u \mapsto u_{rr} + u_{\theta \theta}$ is a completely different operator. (It also doesn't make very much physical sense, because if $r$ has units of length as usual, then $u_{rr}$ and $u_{\theta \theta}$ don't have the same units, so it makes no sense to add them together.)

Comment: That said, there is nothing special about the names, you could change the names of the Cartesian $(x,y)$ to $(r,\theta)$ instead just to be weird, but then you would have $(\rho,\phi)$ or something when you convert *that* to polar coordinates.

Comment: Perhaps one thing that is confusing you is the abuse of notation: when we replace $u(x,y)$ with $u(r,\theta)$, we don't actually mean that the two are mathematically the same function. Instead, given $u(x,y)$ in Cartesian coordinates, converting to polar coordinates gives us a new function. To be explicit I'll call it $w$, and say that it represents "$u$ in polar coordinates". Then $w(r,\theta)=u(r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta))$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you! So the formula represents $\Delta u$ in terms of $\omega$ and reads $\Delta u = \omega_{rr}+\frac{1}{r} \omega_{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\omega_{\theta \theta}$, right? And RHS of this formula can be regarded as the definition of Laplacian in the "new" space represented by polar coordinates?

Comment: That's right (where the arguments to $\Delta u$ are as before).

Comment: @Ian Arguments of LHS are $(x,y)$ and arguments of RHS are $(r,\theta)$?

Comment: Properly speaking, $\Delta u(r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta))=w_{rr}(r,\theta)+\frac{1}{r} w_r(r,\theta) + \frac{1}{r^2} w_{\theta \theta}(r,\theta)$.

Comment: @Ian You should probably write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Laplacian is initially defined in Cartesian coordinates. If you switch to polar coordinates, then you are still dealing with the same operator, so you need to use the chain rule to get a form which only involves derivatives with respect to $r$ and $\theta$. Thus the operator $u \mapsto u_{rr} + u_{\theta \theta}$ is completely different from the Laplacian. It's also a pretty physically useless operator, because usually $r$ has units of length, so usually $u_{rr}$ and $u_{\theta \theta}$ have different units, and therefore cannot be added.

It is a bit confusing that we use the same name for the function $u$ in Cartesian and polar coordinates. But the two are not actually the same mathematical function (even though they represent the same physical quantity in different coordinate systems). Using the same name is really an abuse of notation. If we were being really precise, we would introduce $w(r,\theta)=u(r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta))$. Here $w$ is "the polar coordinate representation of $u$". Then the chain rule is really telling us that

$$\Delta u(r \cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)) = w_{rr}(r,\theta) + \frac{1}{r} w_r(r,\theta) + \frac{1}{r^2} w_{\theta \theta}(r,\theta).$$